# LIMITs on data.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, data-explorer

```
SELECT Id, DisplayName FROM Users ORDER BY CreationDate DESC LIMIT 10;
```

That query didn't work on data.stackexchange.com. I guess LIMIT isn't a key word. As such how would I go about doing a LIMIT?

Comment: It's SQL Server not MySQL... Use TOP.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want [`TOP`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql):

```
SELECT TOP(10) Id, DisplayName FROM Users ORDER BY CreationDate DESC
```

Comment: It's SQL Server 2012, so you can also use the new (pretty verbose) `offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only`

Answer (score 3):

Promoting the [comment from balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173342/limits-on-data-stackexchange-com/376994#comment515369_173343) to a full fledged answer.

Since SQL Server 2012 you can also use the OFFSET / FETCH syntax as extension of the Order By clause. This is useful if you don't want to the top rows but some set in the middle (think paging):

```
SELECT Id
     , DisplayName 
FROM Users 
ORDER BY CreationDate DESC
offset 0 rows
fetch next 10 rows only
```

See also [Using OFFSET and FETCH to limit the rows returned](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned) in the SQL Server documentation.